# merge sorted querysets - django

Tags: python, django, list

I am querying two models:

```
q1 = sorted(Model1.objects.filter(name__iexact=name), key = lambda p: p.sumjournals)
q2 = sorted(Model2.objects.filter(name__iexact=name), key = lambda p: p.sumbooks)
```

`sumbooks, sumjournals` gives the sum of all books and journals respectively.

pseudo result is:

```
q1 = [1, 3, 5, 8, 10]
q2 = [3, 6, 8, 11, 14]
```

I want: `all = [1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 8, 8, 10, 11, 14 ]`. Numbers are object here.

I tried

```
all = []
all.extend(y for y in (q1) if y)
all.extend(y for y in (q2) if y)
```

But the problem is that I am getting different ordered results everytime i load the page. Why is this happening and How can i achieve what i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools

joined = itertools.chain(q1, q2)
sorter = lambda x: x.sumbooks if has_attr(x, 'sumbooks') else x.sumjournals
all = sorted(joined, key = sorter)
```

refer to [hasattr](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#hasattr) and [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) documentation for details

Comment: so i better dont do the lambda thing in q1 and q2, right? cos i am doing it later in sorted()?

Comment: Yes, most likely you don't need to sort `q1` and `q2`, I'm just not sure how well itertools play with django querysets, as they are lazy evaluated (if I'm not mistaking). Anyway, if lazy evaluation cause any trouble with itertools you can always materialize the queryset by `materialized_q1 = list(q1)`.

Comment: yeah, i did so now. but it is still giving me everytime different orders.. very weird.. any idea? :(

Comment: IS this the final step in processing this query? If later on you convert this into dictionary - sorting is absolutely useless as built-in dictionaries are unsorted.

Comment: this is the last step, then i render to template as list.

Comment: Looks like it's time for some debugging for you, because it works for me. One little suggestion (but it shouldn't help solve the problem): you shadow built-in `all` function, I would rename `all` to `result` or something like that. Again, it shouldn't help solve the problem, but, well, weird things already happening here :)